# PHP Mysql field value based on another field value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Not sure how to ask this but I have a database of products and their prices. The price consist of 3 columns (Current Price, Discounted Price, Previous Price).

I use fgetcsv() to read a CSV of new records then the Mysqli query below to insert or update new records to my database:

`$query = "INSERT INTO products (prodname,currprice,prevprice,discprice) VALUES ('$EachRow[0]','$EachRow[1]','$EachRow[2]','$EachRow[3]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currprice='$EachRow[1]';";`

The problem is for existing products. I only want to update their currprice if their prevprice is different than the currprice and to update them, the new currprice must be used. I was hoping for something in mysqli like

`"UPDATE IF $EachRow[1]<>currprice SET prevprice=currprice,currprice='$EachRow[1]'"`

Basically for existing records, if the current price is has changed, I want the previous currprice recorded as prevprice before updating currprice to the new $EachRow[1].

Is there a way to make this happen? Can we make IF statements in mysqli query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `IF` clause after `Duplicate Key Update`

```
INSERT INTO tbl (name, some_column, some_other)
VALUES (username, some_data)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
some_other = IF(some_other > somevalue, "in_case_if_cond_is_true", "in_case_if_cond_is_false")
```

These are called [Flow Control Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), MariaDB control flow [Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-function/)

According to Maria DB

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

> If `expr1` is `TRUE` `(expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL)` then `IF()` returns
>   `expr2`; otherwise it returns `expr3`

Comment: is `>` the right and only operator for `not equal to` in these cases?

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you.

Comment: It seem to be failing :( I'm getting a "You have an error in your syntax, please check MariaDB" error

The part where the error seem to be happening is at

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prevprice= IF(currprice > $Price, currprice)`

Comment: You never mentioned you are using MariaDB, anyway, there was a typo in my code above. I have fixed it, so you can better understand now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use normal where condition

```
UPDATE table_name SET `prevprice` = `currprice`, `currprice`='$EachRow[1]' WHERE `currprice` != '$EachRow[1]'
```

use quote (') with your variable if you need